# iOS How to create schedule local notification by days, weeks, and hourly Swift

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I want to create a schedule for users, for now, I know how to create a specific time, but I want to create such notification for example for separate days, or only for a weekend, or for days which user which setup. 
 My code for hourly notification:

```
var notifTime = Int()
var notifMin = Int()

func test() {
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
      content.title = "Test"
        content.body = "It's test bro"
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

        let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        let now = Date()
        var components = gregorian.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: now)

        components.hour = notifTime
        components.minute = notifMin
        components.second = 0

        let date = gregorian.date(from: components)!

        let triggerDaily = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour,.minute,.second,], from: date)
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerDaily, repeats: true)

        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "any", content: content, trigger: trigger)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
}
```

For time pick up i use date picker.

[image]

So how I can create schedule notification per days?

Comment: I think you are not assigning any value to notifTime and notifMin so, you getting issue. So, can you show the logic behind notifTime and notifMin ?, So, it's easy to find a solution.

Comment: @Pratik Sodha for this to variable notifTime and notifMin i get data from date picker

Answer (score 0):

```
let startDate = Date()
let triggerDate = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.weekday,.hour,.minute], from: startDate)
```

Set `startDate` as first notification time date.
Hope it's work for you.